# О невежах и невеждах

Tags: грамотная-речь

Услышала в передаче слово "невежДа" и задумалась. С одной стороны - "ведать", но с другой, есть устаревшее слово "вежество". И как же все-таки правильно: "невежда" или "невежа"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Происхождение у этих слов общее: от праслав. *vedь,* veda «знание». Из праслав. *vedja в ст.-сл. яз. развилось слово **вежда** «знающий» (*dj > жд). В древнерусском  *вежда* превратилась в **вежа**. От др.-рус. слова **вежа** и ст.-сл. **вежда** в рус.яз. и появились производные с отрицат. частицей *не-*: **невежа** «несведущий» и «грубый, неучтивый чел.», **невежда** «малообразованный чел.», «неуч».

Таким образом, в современном русском языке это разные слова. **Невежа** - 1. Грубый, невоспитанный человек; 2. разг. = Невежда. **Невежда** - необразованный, малосведущий человек; неуч.